# Summary of malformed URL's?

Tags: iis, security

I am working on a IIS http module that has the purpose of blocking our various common malformed URL's that can be used to attack my site.

Are there any good reference of what kind of URL's to look out for?

I know there is the URLScan project, but I want to understand the various attack vectors.

Answer (score 1):

While you are asking for a blacklist, a more valuable approach is using a whitelist, i.e., think about which URLs are valid. This will minimize the chances of missing a specific URL pattern that can be used in a malicious fashion, but that is not caught by your blacklist pattern(s).